# Notification Duration for HeadsUp

Tags: java, android, notifications, heads-up-notifications

Is it possible to set the duration of the headsup notification to unlimited? right now its displayed just for 5 seconds. Already tried different things like changing the category. But the duration always is 5 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
Notification notification =
            notificationBuilder
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setContentText("TKSE Werk Duisburg")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tk_individual_signet_logo)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(viewNotificationHeadsUp)                                                      .setCustomContentView(viewNotificationSmall)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setVibrate(new long[20]).build();
```

Tried the same things like on this thread: [Controlling Android Notification Duration for HeadsUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850240/controlling-android-notification-duration-for-headsup) but it did not help me.

Interesting fact:
On my Developer Phone a Samsung S5 mini -> its displayed with no time limit
On another Developer Phone a Samsung S7 -> its displayed 5 seconds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work. I have added extra `onGoing(true)` & `category call` for notification category.

```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    // assuming your main activity
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), 0);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

PS. import android.app.Notification; for setting notification category (call)

**Update Android 10**

You need to add priority along with category for on going notification.

```
val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, CallActivity::class.java)
val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
    .setContentText("(919) 555-1234")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)

    // Use a full-screen intent only for the highest-priority alerts where you
    // have an associated activity that you would like to launch after the user
    // interacts with the notification. Also, if your app targets Android 10
    // or higher, you need to request the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission in
    // order for the platform to invoke this notification.
    .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)

val incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build()
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#create-high-priority-notification)

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Upvote and Thanks was my responsibility.

Comment: Not working for me in android 10 device, After 5 seconds, headsup notification is gone.

Comment: @mdroid Got any solution for android 10?

Comment: @Vikrant_Dev, No I didn't get the solution yet.

Comment: Added update for ongoing notification on Android 10 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this page and it has worked

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive

```
    val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, CallActivity::class.java)
val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
    .setContentText("(919) 555-1234")
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)



// Use a full-screen intent only for the highest-priority alerts where you
    // have an associated activity that you would like to launch after the user
    // interacts with the notification. Also, if your app targets Android 10
    // or higher, you need to request the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission in
    // order for the platform to invoke this notification.
    .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
```

and of course use with foregroundService

```
val incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build()
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try that solution (the one that you have posted as the link..) but after doing that change *dont forget to change the `NOTIFICATION_ID`* sometimes if the notification id is not changed **some of the previous attributes of the notifications stays** .. so

**Change the notification id when you change any attribute of notification builder**

Comment: Same reactrion. Headsup notification is just shown for 5 seconds.